# How to open a changing URL using python wildcard?

Tags: python, wildcard, urllib

There is a file with the meteorological forecast in a web. The URL example is as follows

```
http://aaaa.bbbb.org/bulletins/METAREA3W.FORECAST.0600.0107561654901.html
```

I can read that using

```
requests.get("http://aaaa.bbbb.org/bulletins/METAREA3W.FORECAST.0600.0107561654901.html")
```

but some strings in the URL change, and I would like to use a wildcard as:

```
requests.get("http://aaaa.bbbb.org/bulletins/METAREA3W.FORECAST.***********.html")
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can't use wildcards for URLs like that. You could generate a list of URLs according to some pattern, but you have to tell us what's the pattern, so we can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute all the relevant real URLs and loop over these real URLs. There's no equivalent of `ls http://aaaa.bbbb.org/bulletins/METAREA3W.FORECAST.***********.html` in web servers.